# after storing the file in the storage I can not update the path of the storage link in the database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to update the file path to the database using Laravel Storage facades. But the **cover_photo** field is not updating. the **avater** field is updating correctly.

When a user is created using the factory method I set the default path for both the avater and cover_photo field. This is the code for the factory section

```
    $factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;
    $rndNum = rand(0,1);
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'slug' => str_slug($faker->name),
        'gender' => rand(0,1),
        'avater' => $rndNum == 0 ?'public/defaults/avaters/female.png':'public/defaults/avaters/male.png',
        'cover_photo' => 'public/defaults/avaters/cover.jpg',
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Profile::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'location' => null,
        'about' => null,
        'user_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\User::class)->create()->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

In the database seeder i use this code to run the factory

```
public function run()
{
    factory(\App\Profile::class,6)->create();
}
```

Now in the profileController section when i try to update the database fields by this code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'location' => 'required|max:55',
        'about'    =>  'required|max:1024',
    ]);
    $profile = Profile::where('user_id',$id)->with('user')->first();

    if ($request->hasFile('avater')){
        $profile->user->update([
            'avater' => $request->avater->store('public/users/avaters/'),
        ]);
    }
    if($request->hasFile('cover_photo')){
        $profile->user->update([
            'cover_photo' => $request->cover_photo->store('public/users/avaters/'),
        ]);
    }
    $profile->update([
        'location' => $request->location,
        'about' => $request->about,
    ]);
    return $profile;
    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Profile Updated!',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->back()->with($notification);


}
```

And then i used this code to view the image in the blade file

```
<img src="{{Storage::url(''.$user->cover_photo)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

**Problem is that the path to the cover_photo in the database is not updating. What can I do?**
[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38dQu.png)

Comment: After some thinking and doing some work i have found out that when i am updating the field called **cover_photo** is in another table in the database. So I am actually updating only the one table not the field in another table called **users**. `$path1 = $request->file('cover_photo')->store('public/users/avaters/');
      $profile->user->cover_photo = $path1;
      $profile->user->save();`

Comment: sorry i have made big mistake during update of database. I did not mention  $fillable field and also during the creation of the user i assign wrong value to the field. After fixing this i can use simple relational function to update the data.